# Stack implementation with array

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I am trying to implement stack with array in C. But I guess my push function is not correct.(Maybe there are some other mistakes) Because when I run the code, it prints "Stack is empty!" two times.

How can I solve this problem and is this implementation logic is true?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

 typedef struct stack
 {
     int top;
     int items[SIZE];
 }stack;

 void push(int a, stack st)
 {
     if((st.top + 1) != SIZE)
     {
         st.top++;
         st.items[st.top] = a;
     }
     else
     {
         printf("\nStack is full!");
     }
 }

 void pop(stack st)
 {
     if(st.top != -1)
     {
         st.top--;
     }
     else
     {
         printf("\nStack is empty!");
     }
 }

 void printList(stack st)
 {
     int i;
     for(i = 0; i < st.top + 1; i++)
     {
         printf("%d -> ", st.items[i]);
     }
     puts("");
 }

 int main(void)
 {
     stack stack1;
     stack1.top = -1;

     stack stack2;
     stack2.top = -1;

     push(3, stack1);
     push(5, stack1);
     push(7, stack1);

     printList(stack1);

     pop(stack1);
     printList(stack1);

     pop(stack1);
     printList(stack1);
 }
```

Comment: There must be thousands of duplicates of this. All will tell you that C passes arguments *by value*, meaning they are *copied* into the functions argument variables. Modifying a copy will not modify the original. That's why you will see passing structures in other code being passed as *pointers* (which is used to ***emulate** pass by reference*).

Comment: Please end messages with newlines; you don't normally need newlines at the start.  Output may not appear until there is a newline, so newline at the beginning can lead to confusion.

Comment: Change all functions to accept `stack_t *st` instead of `stack_t st` and change (e.g.) `st.top` into `st->top` in them. In `main`, change all calls to stack functions to be (e.g.) `push(3, &stack1)` This is because of the pass-by-value [which you _don't_ want] to [an emulation of] pass-by-reference [which you _do_ want].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your stack implementation is wrong.**Using gdb you can verify this**.You are passing structure **as value you should pass as address**.

On gdb you can see

In main
gdb) p &stack1
$4 = (stack *) 0x7fffffffddf0

In push fn

(gdb) p &st
$3 = (stack *) 0x7fffffffdd90

both are different.

correct code is given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

typedef struct stack
{
        int top;
        int items[SIZE];
}stack;

void push(int a, stack *st)
{
        if((st->top + 1) != SIZE)
        {
                st->top++;
                st->items[st->top] = a;
        }
        else
        {
                printf("\nStack is full!");
        }
}

void pop(stack *st)
{
        if(st->top != -1)
        {
                st->top--;
        }
        else
        {
                printf("\nStack is empty!");
        }
}

void printList(stack *st)
{
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < st->top + 1; i++)
        {
                printf("%d -> ", st->items[i]);
        }
        puts("");
}

int main(void)
{
        stack stack1;
        stack1.top = -1;

        stack stack2;
        stack2.top = -1;

        push(3, &stack1);
        push(5, &stack1);
        push(7, &stack1);

        printList(&stack1);

        pop(&stack1);
        printList(&stack1);

        pop(&stack1);
        printList(&stack1);
}
```